# show more/show less text without bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

show more/show less text without bootstrap?

there's any method to do exactly
[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/8cYFj/320/)

```css
.in.collapse+a.btn.showdetails:before
{
    content:'Hide details «';
}
.collapse+a.btn.showdetails:before
{
    content:'Show details »';
}
```

```html
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4 collapse-group">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
           <p class="collapse" id="viewdetails">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <a class="btn showdetails" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewdetails"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

without using bootstrap.min.js?
because i already use app.min.js

and if i keep using bootstrap.min.js that makes my dropdown menu wont expand

Comment: What is `app.min.js`? Does that control your dropdown menu? Don't see why including `bootstrap.min.js` would affect `app.min.js`, unless there is some naming conflict. Do you get any js errors in console when your menu won't expand?

Comment: @Starscream1984 yes it is, that control my dropdown and slide menu, yeah i guess its about naming conflict, but after i change every name the problem still same

Comment: @Starscream1984 it said "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6" when i click that, almost every bootstrap.min.js code labeled as with pink mark

Comment: @KevinItsukawa Looks like you don't have a reference to jQuery. How are you using bootstrap then?

Comment: Yep, bootstrap javascript needs a reference to jQuery. That error could be stopping your own code from executing. @Patel - you can use the bootstrap CSS for a lot of it's features without needing the javascript file.

Comment: @Patel  thanks guys lol, i really didn't see that one, problem solved :D